# Who first estimated the minimal size of a model for a satisfiable formula of monadic first-order logic?

Tags: mathematical-logic, logic

Lowenheim (1915) is credited with the first proof of the decidability of semantic validity over the monadic fragment of first-order predicate logic. However, I find no reference in his proof to an upper bound on the size of the finite model whose construction is guaranteed if the formula is satisfiable. This is surprising since the bound is not hard to guess - it is equal to $2^k \cdot r$ where $k$ is the number of distinct (monadic) predicate letters and $r$ the number of individual variables. Does anyone know who the first person to discover this bound was?

References:

LÖWENHEIM, LEOPOLD

[1915] On Possibilities in the Calculus of Relatives, in van Heijenoort (ed.) [1967], pp. 228–251.

VAN HEIJENOORT, JEAN (ED.)

[1967] From Frege to Gödel; a source book in mathematical logic, 1879-1931. Cambridge, Harvard University Press.